# How to send email from R and windows 7

Tags: r, email, sms, sendmail, quantmod

I'm trying to send an email from R. I'm running windows 7 and it does not recognize the sendmailR package. Please help!!

Error in library(sendmailR) : there is no package called ‘sendmailR’

> library(sendmailR)
>   Error in library(sendmailR) : there is no package called ‘sendmailR’
>   library(mail)
>   Error in library(mail) : there is no package called ‘mail’

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you do `install.packages("sendmailR")` to first install the add on package?

Comment: Is there a way to execute a batch file from R???

Comment: Do you have an example on how to send an email from R?? There is not much online about this topic.. I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Type the following into the console `?sendmailR::sendmail` as `?` gets help topics on manual functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are off and running, great.  But this might also assist.  A very helpful person sent me this description for how to send emails with R.  His last name was Kristjborn, from Sweden, but I can't otherwise credit him.

Steps needed, after signing up at postmarkapp.com and getting Hadley's script at https://gist.github.com/hadley/5707759

1. Copy your API key from postmarkapp.com (in Credentials tab under your server name)
2. In R, write:

   Sys.setenv(POSTMARKAPP_API_KEY= your-copied-api-key-here)
   Sys.setenv(POSTMARKAPP_API_KEY=  “xxxx”)  # with quotes
3. In the file from which you want to send the email, use the following code:

   source('../postmarkapp.r')  #or the path to your postmarkapp.r wherever you store it

   source("C:/Users/R/Documents/R/R Scripts/sendgmailwithpostmarkfromHadleygist.R")

   mailtext <- "Good morning, \nThis should be sending you emails from R in no time. \nBest regards, \nSender"

   send_email(to = '...', from = '...', subject = '...', body = mailtext, attachments = 'path-to-file')  # or skip attachments

This should work. However, if the code fails in sourcing the postmarkapp, it is probably due to dependent Libraries. The app depends on:

> library(base64enc) library(RJSONIO) library(httr)

If any of these are not installed you need to do so. Note that httr is stored on github which needs to be installed using install_github from the devtools package: http://www.rstudio.com/projects/devtools/